# what is $\mathbb{Q}(i) \otimes \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, tensor-products

Let $i = \sqrt{\mathbf{-1}}$ we can define the extension $\mathbb{Q}(i)/\mathbb{Q}$.  Then we have that:
$$ \sqrt{\mathbf{-1}} \in \mathbb{Q}(i) \otimes \mathbb{R}$$

but what is that ring on the RHS?  We could go even further and define:
$$ [\sqrt{\mathbf{-1}}]_\infty = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{\mathbf{-1}}\end{array}\right] \in \mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Q}(i) \otimes \mathbb{R}) $$
This group makes even less sense if I can't compute the tenor product ring $\mathbb{Q}\otimes \mathbb{R}$ (or it's generalization).

---

There's ambiguity if the tensor product is $\otimes_\mathbb{Z}$ or $\otimes_\mathbb{Q}$ or $\otimes_\mathbb{R}$, however I did find this relation:

$$ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1}) \otimes \mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})}$$

Then it might be tensor product over $\mathbb{Q}$ as the Wikipedia page on [adèles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adele_ring#Alternative_definition_of_the_adele_ring_of_an_algebraic_number_field) has:

$$ \mathbb{A}_F = \mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q} \otimes_\mathbb{Q} F \simeq \Big( (\hat{\mathbb{Z}} \times \mathbb{R} ) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q} \Big) \otimes_\mathbb{Q} F $$
and *that* object is rather comlicated since I don't know if $\otimes_\mathbb{Z}$ and $\otimes_\mathbb{Q}$ can be easily [switched around](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property).

Comment: I think you wanted to use $\otimes$ also in the title.

Comment: Fixed.  Also, I found a nice discussion [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf) and [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod2.pdf) but not the computation $\mathbb{Q} \otimes \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Is that $\otimes$ to be read as $\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}}$ or possibly $\otimes_{\Bbb{Q}}$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I have added some thoughts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(A) $\mathbb{Q}(i) \otimes_\mathbb Q \mathbb{R}=\frac {\mathbb{Q}[X]}{(X^2+1)}\otimes_\mathbb Q \mathbb{R}=\frac {\mathbb{R}[X]}{(X^2+1)}=\mathbb C$
(B) $\mathbb{Q}(i) \otimes_\mathbb Z \mathbb{R}\stackrel {\bigstar}{=}\mathbb{Q}(i) \otimes_\mathbb Q \mathbb{R} \stackrel {\operatorname {(A)}}{=}\mathbb C$

(i) The genuine reason for the equality $\bigstar$  is the calculation $$\frac {1} {17}q \otimes_\mathbb Z r=\frac {q} {17}\otimes_\mathbb Z 17\frac {r}{17}=17\frac {q} {17}\otimes_\mathbb Z \frac {r}{17}=q\otimes_\mathbb Z\frac {1}{17}r$$ which proves that we can move $\frac {1} {17}$ from the left of $\otimes_\mathbb Z$ to the right even though *a priori* only integers can be moved from the left to the right of $\otimes_\mathbb Z$.
[As is well known, $17$ denotes an arbitrary positive integer]

(ii) The formal reason for equality $\bigstar$ is ...that there is a proof !
 For example in [Bourbaki, Commutative Algebra](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Commutative_Algebra.html?id=Bb30CjGW7EAC&redir_esc=y) Chapter II, §2.7, Proposition 18, page 75.